# Add domain to home server

Tags: linux, server

I bought myself a second computer as my home server and installed ubuntu server 20.04.
I also purchased a dedicated IP from my provider.
My server is connected via a router, I gave it a static IP 192.168.5.5 inside the router's network and configured port forwarding.

I checked that according to my IP that the provider gave me, you can now see my site that I launched for the test.

Next, I plan to buy several domains and create several small sites on my server.
I would also like to be able to use subdomains.

I have absolutely no experience in setting up servers, what should I do? Perhaps there are articles that fit my purpose? I hope for your help

Comment: You will need to configure your domain's DNS settings to point those domains and subdomains to your IP.

Comment: This question is more suited for unix stackexchange. This forum is for programming questions, not server administartion. Ask it on unix.stackexchange and on reddit, you might get a lot of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, install and configure firewall. This is your *first step*. Nowadays I use `shorewall` (and `shorewall6` for ipv6), which is a versatile and hard tool, there are also `firewalld` `ufw` that I'm not a fan of but you could be, and you can also write raw `iptables` rules where you can learn *a lot*. Then setup `fail2ban`. Open only ssh port to the outside, disable password login - enable only public key password login. I also have `logwatch` for monitoring. There are also security auditing/scanning/problems detecting tools.

> buy several domains

This all depends. There are some providers (cloudflare, aws, some big one) that you *may* configure the DNS names in some web-ui with just clicking and typing the domain you just bought. Then the provider servers as a DNS server for you.

If you want want the hard usual normal way, then you buy the domain and set your server to be a DNS server. `named` is the usual DNS server service. You configure `named` to serve your subdomains with zone files. Then other servers (DNS providers of other internet users) ask your server which domain is which ip address. With only one server with only one external ip, you can just set a `*.yourdomain.com` and be done with it.

> create several small sites on my server

Http servers respond on specific domain names - you have to configure your http server on which domains you want it to respong. The most common http servers are lighttpd, nginx and apache. You have to configure on which domain what should be served. Then you then want to setup https to give yourself privacy - setup `certbot` from letsencrypt to generate certificates.

This post is rather a short summary of topics you might want to research, rather then steps. Research and learn, then implement, do not follow anything blindly.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow below steps.
Configure virtual host in you server for each site.
`For example:`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
    ServerName test.example.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/test/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where test.example.com is your subdomain and test is the root directory of this domain
Point each domain to your server public ip in dns.